# how to assign particular value from logstash output

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

In logstash I am getting this output, however, I am trying to get repo: "username/logstashrepo" only from this output. Please share your thoughts how to grep only that value and assign to variable.

```
message: "github_audit: {"actor_ip":"192.168.1.1","from":"repositories#create","actor":"username","repo":"username/logstashrepo","user":"username","created_at":1416299104782,"action":"repo.create","user_id":1033,"repo_id":44744,"actor_id":1033,"data":{"actor_location":{"location":{"lat":null,"lon":null}}}}",
@version: "1",
@timestamp: "2014-11-18T08:25:05.427Z",
host: "15-274-145-63",
type: "syslog",
syslog5424_pri: "190",
timestamp: "Nov 18 00:25:05",
actor_ip: "192.168.1.1",
from: "repositories#create",
actor: "username",
repo: "username/logstashrepo",
user: "username",
created_at: 1416299104782,
action: "repo.create",
user_id: 1033,
repo_id: 44744,
actor_id: 1033,
```

I am using this in my config file:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 8088
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 8088
    type => syslog
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:host} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    ]
    overwrite => ["host", "message"]
  }
  if [message] =~ /^github_audit: / {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^github_audit: %{GREEDYDATA:json_payload}"]
    }

    json {
      source => "json_payload"
      remove_field => "json_payload"
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I actually posted the question here, for some reason I can't edit and followup.

[how to grep particulr field from logstash output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987052/how-to-grep-particulr-field-from-logstash-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the [json filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/json) store the expanded JSON object in a subfield. Use the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate) to move the "repo" field into the toplevel and delete the whole subfield. Partial example from the json filter and onwards:

```
json {
  source => "json_payload"
  target => "json"
  remove_field => "json_payload"
}

mutate {
  rename => ["[json][repo]", "repo"]
  remove_field => "json"
}
```

Comment: sorry, one more doubt, can i save this particular value (repo: "username/logstashrepo") into any variable or file from above output, I need to use this value for execution      thanks in advance

Comment: Logstash has several output plugins available. You could e.g. save the field or message to a file or run a command.

Comment: Hi , I've used  to remove other fields from my output and I need only repo: "username/logstashrepo" from output , i've used this method, but I am not getting "repo: "username/logstashrepo" only    json {
      source => "json_payload"
      remove_field => "json_payload"
    }
mutate {
  rename => ["[json][repo]", "repo"]
  remove_field => ["[json][syslog5424_pri]"]
  remove_field => ["[json][host]"]
  remove_field => ["[json][type]"]
}